# .zfs folder's missing, but snapshots are still there and mountable (inode trouble?)

Tags: zfsonlinux, shadow-copies, openzfs

```
$ sudo zfs list -t snapshot | grep childDataset3
```

a whole bunch are listed as expected (e.g. pool/dataset/childDataset3@today)

```
$ ls /pool/dataset/childDataset3/.zfs
ls: cannot access '/pool/dataset/childDataset3/.zfs': No such file or directory
```

I have other child datasets, and I can see the snapshot dir inside .zfs for them; and, I can even mount a snapshot from the above list from the one troublesome dataset (so they exist, just not as a nice list in a normal spot that users can dip into):

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/tempShadow
$ sudo mount -t zfs pool/dataset/childDataset3@today /mnt/tempShadow
```

i.e. I can browse one snapshot of files this way; also noteworthy, when I run the disk filesystems command with show inodes, all of the working datasets and child datasets show up EXCEPT for the one I'm having trouble with (what I'm calling "childDataset3"):

```
$ df -i

pool                               232594013966       9 232594013957    1% /pool
pool/dataset                       232600679652 6665695 232594013957    1% /pool/dataset
pool/dataset/childDataset1         232596006126 1992169 232594013957    1% /pool/dataset/childDataset1
pool/dataset/childDataset2         232594839509  825552 232594013957    1% /pool/dataset/childDataset2
pool/dataset/childDataset4         230211379723 3040916 230208338807    1% /pool/dataset/childDataset4
```

so is there a way to re-create the child dataset's inode?  (forgive me if I'm totally saying that wrong)

using zfs version 0.7.12-2+deb10u2 if that matters

my backup solution is to switch users to the replicated dataset (on another server), and then destroy this dataset, then send a snapshot back (but I want to avoid this, because 32TB doesn't just pop over)

Answer (score 2):

The `.zfs` directory is special: try to first chdir into it and then listing it.

In other words: `cd /pool/dataset/childDataset3/.zfs/ ; ls`

Comment: all of my snapshot dirs behave normally except for one

Answer (score 0):

since it doesn't seem like anyone has an answer (or they do, but just not finding my post), I'll answer my question:

note that albeit new snapshots are being made on this glitched child dataset, and I can at least mount those snapshots (albeit can't browse .zfs/snapshot)...
...when I look through said mount, I now see that new files are **not** there, and the snapshots are taking up 0B of space, and zfs list is not showing that the used space is growing (like "du -s /pool/dataset/childDataset3" would)

and, if I "sudo zfs rename pool/dataset/childDataset3 pool/dataset/childDataset3-bad", the /pool/dataset/childDataset3 folder *is still there* with all the data, and path /pool/dataset/childDataset3-bad *doesn't exist*, albeit zfs thinks it exists and consuming space; i.e. my problem is that somehow a folder and dataset are existing together (like when you create a new dataset with the folder existing already: you get a not empty error and can easily re-create the glitch I'm experiencing)

**SOLUTION:**
rename the bogus dataset, destroy the bogus dataset, create a new dataset (same old name you used before for the bogus one), and move the data back (using rsync and remove source flag):

ATTN: if you get an error moving (aka renaming) the folder, then you do not have the same problem as I did (do NOT destroy your dataset if the mv command results in an error)

```
mv /pool/dataset/childDataset3 /pool/dataset/childDataset3-folder
sudo zfs destroy -r pool/dataset/childDataset3
sudo zfs create pool/dataset/childDataset
sudo chown yourUsername /pool/dataset/childDataset
rsync -auAXv --remove-source-files /pool/dataset/childDataset3-folder/ /pool/dataset/childDataset3/ > moveLogs.txt &
# I had to wait a couple weeks (I'm copying 50TB)
find /pool/dataset/childDataset3-folder -empty -type d -delete
# you can run the above find command whenever, and when rsync is done, the find command will remove childDataset3-folder (and if you rsync bails, you can re-run that too)
```

DISCLAIMER: please understand what you're doing when you run a command like destroy, especially with recursive (or use --remove-source-files in rsync); I'm also assuming no one is using the bad dataset (nor is it involved in something like a backup)

Comment: just fyi, I could destroy the dataset first, then rename the left-behind folder (that shared the same name as the dataset), but better to try to mv a dataset's mount folder first (if it errors about resouce busy, DO NOT proceed with the zfs destroy!)